# replicating CHARINDEX with a new user defined function in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, char, migration

Can some one replicate CHARINDEX with new user defined function. (using instr)

```
IF(CHARINDEX('(G)',v_username) = 0) THEN
```

mysql version. If could keep the function same my migration will be become more smooth.

```
IF(INSTR(v_username,'(G)') = 0) THEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.  One approach is to create a [user-defined function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that wraps CharIndex.

```
-- CHARINDEX wrapper.
CREATE FUNCTION INSTR
    (
        @Source     NVARCHAR(255),      -- Search this..
        @Find       NVARCHAR(255)       -- ...for this.
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN   
    RETURN CHARINDEX(@Find, @Source)
END
```

The downside to this approach is UDFs cannot compete, in terms of performance, with native functions.

You might be able to reduce the impact by looking at the [common language runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  The CLR allows you to write functions, SPs, etc that compile to native code.

All things considered; I would recommend you update your code instead.  Although they can be long and painful, migrations are a one-off task.